# Hamburger Menu Not Working On WordPress Site

Tags: php, jquery, css, wordpress, hamburger-menu

Here is my website: 
[drawyourpets.com](http://drawyourpets.com)

I followed the tutorial here: http://www.internetkultur.at/simple-hamburger-drop-down-menu-with-css-and-jquery/, but unfortunately my hamburger menu is always visible (it's only supposed to be visisble from 0-780px) and it doesn't work.

I copied and pasted the code from the HTML section into header.php. The code from the tutorial starts with div class="mobile nav" and ends with it's respective div. I also added

```
<script src="javascript.js"></script>
```

to link header.php to the javascript code from the tutorial. Javascript.js was uploaded to the child theme.

```
<?php
/** * Header template * * @package Portfolio Press */?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>">

<script src="javascript.js"></script>

<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() .
'/js/html5.js' ); ?>">
</script><![endif]-->

<?php wp_head(); ?></head><body <?php body_class(); ?>><div id="page">  
<header id="branding">
<div class="col-width">
<?php $heading_tag = ( is_home() || is_front_page() ) ? 'h1' : 'div'; ?
>           

<div class="logo">              
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); 
?>
"rel="home">                    
<img src="<?php echo esc_url( portfoliopress_get_option( 'logo' ) ); ?
>" alt="<?php echo bloginfo( 'name' ) ?>">  
</a>            
</div>          

<div class="site-description">              
<h1 id="pets">DRAW YOUR PETS</h1>               
<h3 id="italic">-The Creative Side-
</h2>           
</div>          
<div class="clear clearfix">
</div>          
<div class="site-navigation primary-navigation" role="navigation">

<div class="mobile-nav">
<div class="menu-btn" id="menu-btn">
<div></div>
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
</div>

 <div class="responsive-menu">
    <ul>
       <li><a href="http://drawyourpets.com/">
       HOME</a>
       </li>
       <li>
       <a href="http://drawyourpets.
       com/index.php/audio/">
       AUDIO
       </a>
       </li>
       <li><a href="http://drawyourpets.com/index.php/video-3/">
       VIDEO
       </a>
       </li>
       <li>
       <a href="http://
       drawyourpets.com/index.php/other/">
       OTHER</a>
       </li>
       </ul>
   </div>
 </div> 

<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu_class'|
=> 'nav-menu' ) ); ?>           

</div>  
<div id="main">     
<div class="site-wrapper">
```

Besides that, I just added the CSS from the tutorial into my child theme stylesheet with this media query above it:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 780px) .menu-btn div {
```

So I'm not sure what I've done wrong or what I need to do to fix it. Let me know if you have any ideas. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script src="javascript.js"></script>
```

Firstly, the path is wrong; 404;

```
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/javascript.js"></script>
```

bloginfo('template_url'); This is your path of theme, you can upload the javascript.js to the corresponding path

Secondly, the "javascript.js" need "jquery.js"; So you must add this behind "jquery.js"

Comment: What do you mean by that? Do I need to change javascript.js to jquery.js? - I tried this and nothing happened.

Comment: <?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/javascript.js

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm still confused by "the 'javascript.js' need 'jquery.js'"

Does this mean I put the code that you suggested after the code that @Farizdev suggested like this? 

<script src="<https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.2.min.js></script>
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/javascript.js"></script>

Comment: You can add "javascript.js" in the "footer.php"

Comment: <?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?> Do you know this path?

Comment: <?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/portfolio-press-child/js/javascript.js"></script>

Comment: portfolio-press-child/js/javascript.js - this is where the file is located

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107803/discussion-between-jian-dan-and-happyhands31).

Answer (score 1):

No, you just include a jQuery files. Add this :

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.2.min.js"></script>
```

above your javascript.js

Comment: What do you mean by "above you javascript.js"?

Does that mean I write this? <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.2.min.js"></script>
<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/javascript.js"></script>

Comment: Yeah, just try it and post it again if you got any error here :)